# fs.writeFile writing partial data to file

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write some base64 encoded data to a file using `fs.writeFile` using the following snippet

```
fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/files/${file.NAME}`, Buffer.from(data, 'base64'), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('err:', err);
    }
    return console.log('file write complete');
});
```

- This snippet is giving issues for files greater than 65KB, as it writes only 65KB of the total data. But works perfectly for smaller files
- This issue of 65KB files is happening only on few of my servers not all. And even not on my development machine.

Comment: Are you exiting the process immediately without waiting for the entire write to complete?

Comment: @jfriend00 , No I wait for the callback function to be triggered. And do additional stuff there after. Is there something wrong in it